# Facebook auth with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I'm trying to authorize with PHP SDK.

```php
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'xxx',
            'secret' => 'xxx',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user) {
      $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
}

<a href="#" onClick='myWin=window.open("<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>home_url().'/auth.php')); ?>", "", "width=500,height=400");'">Facebook</a>
```

This piece of code should authorize me and get profile. Redirect_url script looks like this

```php
echo "<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'/></head><body><script>
         var form=window.opener.document.createElement(\"form\");
         form.id = \"red\"
         form.action='';
         form.method=\"post\";
         form.target=\"_top\";
         form.style.display=\"none\";
         var input=document.createElement(\"input\");
         input.type=\"hidden\";
         input.name=\"fb_auth\";
         input.value='';form.appendChild(input);
         window.opener.document.body.appendChild(form);
         form.submit();
         window.close();
     </script></body></html>";
```

So `$user` always 0. Where am i wrong?

Comment: I would remove your app secret from your code for a start its not a good idea to show your app secret.

Comment: it's app for testing and not so valuable for me, but you are right :)

Comment: Did you download the latest version of the SDK? 

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

as I don't see "require_once("facebook.php");" anywhere in your code

Comment: yes, i got SDK 1 week ago and add this line include_once('src/facebook.php'); what is more interesting this worked 1 week ago, but now it's not and this is so strange...

Comment: Ah OK, its just that I don't see it in your code, let me test what you have and post back here.

Comment: thank you, i'm waiting, because i have no idea what's wrong